# Django - passing extra arguments into upload_to callable function

Tags: django, django-models

I know that you can use the upload_to parameter to pass a callable function to dynamically alter a FileFied/ImageField, etc. in a Django model.

The function called by upload_to is passed 2 variables, the instance of the non-saved-in-the-database file (instance) and the filename of said instance (filename).

If I'm using an ImageField in a model along with other (Char, etc.) fields, is it possible to get the values from those fields into that same callable function.

for instance.

```
class Badge(models.Model):

  def format_badge_name(instance, filename):
    _filetype = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
    _category = 'foo'
    _name = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
    _filename = "%s-%s-%s%s" % (_category, _name, 'private', _filetype)

    return "badges/%s" % _filename

  name = models.CharField(max_length=16, help_text="Name for Badge")
  file = models.ImageField(upload_to=format_badge_name)
```

Is it possible to pass the values from name (self.name?) into format_badge_name?

Comment: What are you attempting to do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `instance` variable is the `Badge()` instance. You could access it's properties as usual

```
def format_badge_name(instance, filename):
    instance.name
    instance.file
    ...
```

You could name the `instance` `'self'`, and it might be easier to be understood:

```
def format_badge_name(self, filename):
    self.name
    self.file
    ...
```