# Pass variable from view to model before file is saved

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I would like my file upload to be renamed before being saved to disk.  The logic I want to use to set the name would be contained in the view.

I want to pass my getname variable from my view into my model class before saving.  Here is my broken code.

View:

```
getname = 'foo' #I want this string to get passed into upload_to in the model

form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

if form.is_valid(): 

    newdoc = Document()
    newdoc.filename = getname #This line doesn't work
    newdoc.docfile = request.FILES['docfile']
    newdoc.save()
```

Model:

```
class Document(models.Model):

    filename = ''
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to=filename)
```

I have read through several of these links but whenever I touch my code I break it.

http://www.malloc.co/django/django-rename-a-file-uploaded-by-a-user-before-saving/
http://catherinetenajeros.blogspot.com/2013/03/rename-path-when-imagefile-upload.html

Edit: I've revised the code to help make my question more clear.

Comment: Where will `getname` come from? Is it an attribute in the model instance? Could it be? Will be easier if it is but I may have a solution even if not.

Comment: I have revised the original question.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I understand what you want, but I'm wondering where the `getname` will come from each time. Where are you getting `'foo'`? Also, is `filename` in your model some type of Field? I.e. should it be `filename = models.CharField(max_length=10)`?

Comment: @Alex getname comes from what my user types into a textbox on my HTML form.  `getname = request.POST.get('NameBox')`  I'm trying to digest your response below...Thanks for the help thus far.

Comment: OK. Let me know if you have any troubles. If you're not already, I would recommend using a ModelForm` for `DocumentForm`, as it will automate much of the stuff I noted in the example. ModelForm docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you want, assuming `getname` is entered into the form in your view:

First, your model:

```
def upload_function(instance, filename):
    getname = instance.name
    # Add other filename logic here
    return customfilename # Return the end filename where you want it saved.

class Document(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_function) # The upload_to argument sends it to your upload function.
```

In this case, you're creating your own `upload_to` function (here called `upload_function`). You can read about that [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to). When running this function, it will pass the instance as a first argument, so you can access its properties. Thus, we'll access its `name` when creating our filename. Further explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809620/django-passing-extra-arguments-into-upload-to-callable-function).

Now your view:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import DocumentForm
from .models import Document

def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = Document(docfile=request.FILES['file'])
            instance.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/url/')
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
    return render(request, 'upload.html', {'form': form})
```

This view checks your form to make sure it's valid, then saves the uploaded file. Assuming your `DocumentForm` has a field for `name`, this will be assigned first, which means your function for `upload_to` will be able to access it. The sample language for this view came from the Django docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/#handling-uploaded-files-with-a-model).

Please let me know if this works.

Comment: Yes that model works exactly how I want.  In my view I use `newdoc = Document(name=getname, docfile=request.FILES['docfile'])` and everything works perfectly.

Comment: Great! Wasn't sure it would work myself, so I'm glad to hear it did.

Comment: How does calling upload_function without passing any parameters work?

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly , you're looking for something like this ,

```
newdoc.instance.your_attribute = getname
```

Comment: Yes i'm trying to do that.  I have revised my original code to show where I'm getting stuck