# Django viewable or clickable filepath field

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm a little new to the inter-workings of Django and I would like to display a simple dynamic folder path field that opens to the given path when clicked so a user can view all the files in that path. I'm trying to do this in django admin site change form but am unclear and confused of how to do so. Below is my model.

```
class Order(models.Model):
    order_number = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='LS #', unique=True)
    order_name = models.ForeignKey(recs.RecipeControl, related_name='recipe')
    # Something like this is I think what I want.
    folder_path = models.FilePathField(path=get_path)

    def get_path(self):
       return str(self.order_number)+"_"+self.order_name
```

I'm puzzled as how to properly go about this because I can't seem to reference "self" to do this, especially if the record doesn't already exist. I've looked at a few other Q&A's but none of them dealt with the admin site and after a bit of reading I'm convinced that I may have to override one of the save methods but don't understand which one and where to place my method. Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

After reading through the comments recommended below I think what I want is different than what I had originally thought. The folder path still needs to be dynamic.

However, what I'm looking to do is check on new and existing records whether a folder exists in a given directory (MEDIA_ROOT?) based on model data, then create that directory or update it's name if it changes and save the folders path in the FilePathField. I'm pretty confident that this can be done by overriding that save_model method of the ModelAdmin, no?

Comment: I will correcting about your function of `get_path(self):`, perhaps you need instance object field like this sample `get_path(instance, filename):`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7439529/6396981

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dynamic FilePathField question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439336/dynamic-filepathfield-question)